# VPN route establish connection failed

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I am traing to connect from my VPN from work to home but it is failed (my real address is not 12.12.12.12 I chaneged it here).

```
initiating Main Mode IKE_SA Note8[3] to 12.12.12.12
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]
sending packet: from 192.168.222.113[500] to 12.12.12.12[500] (212 bytes)
received packet: from 12.12.12.12[500] to 192.168.222.113[500] (160 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V V ]
received XAuth vendor ID
received DPD vendor ID
received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
sending packet: from 192.168.222.113[500] to 12.12.12.12[500] (244 bytes)
received packet: from 12.12.12.12[500] to 192.168.222.113[500] (244 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
remote host is behind NAT
generating ID_PRO`your text`T request 0 [ ID HASH N(INITIAL_CONTACT) ]
sending packet: from 192.168.222.113[4500] to 12.12.12.12[4500] (108 bytes)
received packet: from 12.12.12.12[4500] to 192.168.222.113[4500] (76 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response`your text` 0 [ ID HASH ]
IDir '10.10.0.2' does not match to '12.12.12.12'
deletin`your text`g IKE_SA Note8[3] between 192.168.222.113[192.168.222.113]...12.12.12.12[%any]
sending DELETE for IKE_SA Note8[3]
generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1142334682 [ HASH D ]
sending packet: from 192.168.222.113[4500] to 12.12.12.12[4500] (92 bytes)
establishing connection 'Note8' failed 


1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen `1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether b8:27:eb:b8:94:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.1.1.1/24 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 169.254.196.71/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever``your text``
inet6 fe80::ba27:eb`your te`your text`xt`ff:feb8:94ac/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether b8:27:eb:ed:c1:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.222.113/24 brd 192.168.222.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
valid_lft 3487sec preferred_lft 3037sec
inet6 fe80::46b5:423:6a9b:9320/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`

I fount solution but I know not much about routing
this can help but I do not knon how to chaneg this according my network

```
sleep 2m
ip route add 89.237.132.0/24 dev ppp0 src 89.237.132.229 table rt2
ip route add default via 89.237.132.225 dev ppp0 table rt2
ip rule add from 89.237.132.229/32 table rt2
ip rule add to 89.237.132.229/32 table rt2

ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.100.213 table rt3
ip route add default via 192.168.100.252 dev eth0 table rt3
ip rule add from 192.168.100.213/32 table rt3
ip rule add to 192.168.100.213/32 table rt3
```

My route at this moment look like this:

```
Destination     Gatewa`your text`y         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.222.57  0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.222.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```